# Bringing in Multiple Animations of a Single Armature to Be Used For One Animation

Tags: animation, rigging, append, nla-editor

I have created 3 animations using one rig in separate .blend files, a walk in place, run in place, and a simple front flip. If I were to create a new file with this rig in it, how would I go about importing the keyframes of each action into one file so I can chain them together? In the future, is it a big mistake to do the animating in separate files?

Comment: I hope this video can help you. Multiple Mixamo animations into a single blend project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGj19kCX9Js

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're in the file you'd like to combine the actions in:

1. Goto `File` >> `Append`
2. In the file manager, navigate to the file with the walk/run/front flip.
3. Click on the actual .blend, you'll see a bunch of datablock categories (Action, Mesh, etc).
4. Click on `Action`.
5. Select on the action you want to import, and click `Append`.
6. You should be able to load this action in the Dopesheet/NLA now.  Note that this action won't update from the original file.  If you wanted that, do the above, except clicking `Append` on the menu, click `Link`.

Answer (score 1):

Using File -> Append and appending the desired actions to the current file should work. In refrerence to your question of whether or not it is best practice, there are multiple things to consider: does it make more sense for your project to have actions split amongst a set of files, or are you just making a short animation, and can therefore afford to keep all of your assets in a common file? That is a project decision which can sometimes be motivated by file size, project complexity and how fragmented and compartmentalized you want your project.